# Integrating twig with react.js

Tags: php, symfony, reactjs, twig

I have successfully built a webapp with php symphony and its twig template system, but now requirement has changed, and I have to make use of node react.js. I have read a handful of documentation on react.js but I am still lost on the best approach for my strict timeframe. Any help on how I can do this safely and quickly is appreciated, even in advanced.
How can someone implement react.js in a template like this?

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
Fill This form
{{ form(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token('action') }}" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

EDIT
Due to the size of my project, restarting form, table and others in react will take months... So I make my symphony app to return the forms and tables html as JSON string and I process the forms in React as if JADE content... I hope this will not surface security threat and I am also asking if it is not too lame. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply put you can't do it quickly. React is a front-end JS framework. Twig is a front-end templating engine. While it is possible to make them work together it doesn't make sense to approach your project from this stance. Using Twig and React together is akin to placing a screwdriver in a screw and then beating on it with a hammer.

It would make more sense to replace your Twig usage entirely with React.

Comment: It is a very large project

Comment: I'm not sure how a large project disqualifies the use of pure React vs.  a Twig/React hybrid. Facebook is more than likely larger than your project. Intermingling Twig and React is just asking for problems in the long term.

Comment: Whilst I completely agree with Aurelia, I have come across projects that are going through a transition and might have components written in Twig that might need to be used in React components whilst the whole code base gets rewritten. Not ideal but it does happen so implementations that make the two work together are definitely useful!

Answer (score 5):

Follow the following steps

1. Create api router version of your normal routers
2. Redirect Router /api to the router
3. Set _format default parameter in your api detail definition to json
4. Build your ReactJS to communicate with your server with Json

These were my emergency response steps when I had the same problem, but I still later went through the rigorous work of converting everything later, because my json were filled with html tags. it helped at time, it gave me chance to buy time

Answer (score 4):

Use react-twig:

```
import ReactTwig from 'react-twig'

<ReactTwig template="Kittens say: {{ variable }}" data={{ variable: 'meow' }} />
```

Comment: Note - this was not available at time of question ! and I think that (as of late 2020) the JS renderer does not have exact parity with the PHP renderer - but it is getting there :)

Answer (score 0):

Another package you can use for react or react-native is react-native-twig, this does not have any reliance on front-end packages, but only used to produce html templates

[@rokebrand/react-native-twig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rokebrand/react-native-twig)

```
  const properties = {
    title: 'hello there',
  }

  const rawTemplate =
    '<div style="border-bottom:1px solid;">\n' +
    '<div style="font-size: 9px; color: rgb(255, 0, 0); text-align: center; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;"><strong>Template</strong><br />\n' +
    '{{title}}</div>\n' +
    '</div>';

  const template = Twig.twig({
    data: rawTemplate,
  });

  console.log(template.render(properties))
  // this will log out the combined html
```