# Templating engine for react.js (gatsby.js)

Tags: html, reactjs, twig, gatsby

I am into this react.js and gatsby.js issue since a while.
But as a senior symfony developer I wonder if there are options 
like TWIG even for gatsby sites?

Now I want to create sites with graphQl data and gatsby. 
Is templating not possible with this new stack?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating twig with react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819213/integrating-twig-with-react-js)

Comment: Yes. I just have to think for react and gatsby in a different way. JSX is kind of a template engine - it grabs data and u are afterwards about to present it to the client. Twig filters, functions and macros were made to bring functionality into html files. JSX can do this out of the box - because u can write just js code into your html.

Answer (score 2):

React is a *JavaScript Library for building user interfaces*, according to their website. It simply provides a clever wrapper UI to build component-based building blocks for an app. Once you grab content or/and data from somewhere—e.g. CMS, file system, Graphql DB, etc—you'll have to `render` them in a format you'd need. You could build a template-like structure via `JSX`, but I don't think React/Gatsby supports a templating engine like Twig.

If you're looking for a JavaScript-based static site generator, **11ty** might be a good alternative, as it supports a whole bunch of templating languages. See [this link](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/).